# How to connect from external devices to htdocs folder using local network ip address in Mamp

Tags: macos, mamp

I want to connect and access the document inside htdocs folder to test my project in a external device.

I google a lot trying to find the solution to this problem and I finally find it by trying it once and again. So I decide to create this post for the one that are struggling to access htdocs folder. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

1. Enable incoming connection by switching the firewall off. Go to General Preferences. Then Security & Privacy, go to Firewall and switch it off.
2. Get you ip address. The address that your local network has given you. You can check it by writing "ifconfig" in the terminal. You will find this:

   ```
   inet 192.XXX.X.XX
   ```
3. Go to your device and type in the URL the following:

   ```
   192.XXX.X.XX:8888/document.php
   ```

   Your IP address:Web Server Port/the document full name

You are in htdocs folder now! :)